# Firebase does not recognize my App Check debug token as valid

Tags: ios, node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-app-check

I configured App Check for my iOS app, i followed the documentation step by step, firebase generated a debug token when i launched my app in the simulator and i configured that token in the firebase console. I'm trying to access my express endpoint (firebase cloud function endpoint) but i always get "unauthorized" as response. This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin/app");
const appCheck = require("firebase-admin/app-check");


const app = express();
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp();
dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());

const appCheckVerification = async (req, res, next) => {
  const appCheckClaims =
      await verifyAppCheckToken(req.header("X-Firebase-AppCheck"));
  if (!appCheckClaims) {
    res.status(401);
    return next("Unauthorized");
  }
  next();
};
const verifyAppCheckToken = async (appCheckToken) => {
  if (!appCheckToken) {
    return null;
  }
  try {
    return appCheck.getAppCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
};

app.post("/", [appCheckVerification], (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  const url = "https://www.example.com";
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${some api key}`,
  };
  axios
      .post(url, body, {headers: headers})
      .then((response) => {
        res.json(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
      });
});
```

I get this specific error: "Decoding App Check token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents the Firebase App Check token"

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error! it was my first time configuring Firebase so it was confusing.

I was sending the debug token itself as the value for the Firebase header, so, obviously it was invalid. In my humble opinion they should specify in the docs that the debug token is like a "tag" for a specific "test device", you identify that device (simulator, etc) with that "tag" and firebase will accept requests from it.

So once you get your debug token and add it to the firebase console, you can start using that test device (in my case, an iOS simulator) to communicate to the firebase resource, but, you have to generate real tokens by using (in my case) `AppCheck.appCheck().token(forcingRefresh: false)`.

Comment: so Diego, where do you put the debug token ? in the documentation it's not specified clearly.

I already got the debug token . and currently i am sending it through header . it keeps getting invalid. so how do you send the debug token to the backend ?

Comment: @DanielWijono you have to go inside firebase console and register your app to use app check, when you do this, there will be an option called "manage debug tokens" or something like that in the "app check" section of your project. There you can paste your token and give it a name like "iPhone pro simulador" or something you recognize easily. You can remove the token from the headers, when you put it in your firebase console, firebase Will recognize the device. From time to time the token will change, so, you have to repeat the process.

Comment: @DanielWijono keep in mind, once you add the debug token to the firebase console, you have to include REAL tokens generated with the SDK in your firebase header. The debug token is only to allow firebase backend to recognize your "simulator" or test device as valid.

Comment: Real tokens generated only can from real device right ? 

If for example the QA needs to test from simulator . Already register the debug Token , then what we need to do ? 

The backend needs to check the debug token that’s registered in firebase console ? Sorry i ask again . I am not quite understand

Comment: No, you can generate real tokens using Firebase SDK, for that tokens to be accepted,  they must come from a real device, but, if you need to use a simulador or testing device, you must register that device using a debug token (the debug token allows firebase to recognize your simulator as a real device). After you register your debug token in the firebase console, you can start doing normal request to firebase sending real tokens as you would with a real device. Do not send the debug token in every request, because that is not it's purpose.

Comment: @DanielWijono so in conclusion, get the debug token from your simulator, register it on the firebase console and follow the docs for doing normal request using real tokens.

Comment: @DanielWijono you are very welcome!